# Using NPM dependencies Locally

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm newbie in React. I want implement [react-emoji-react](https://github.com/conorhastings/react-emoji-react) on single page react application without nodejs. Can I do it?

I have basic react code like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Basic Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Basic Example</h1>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="../../build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="../../build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script>
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can I include react-emoji-react directly to script above? I'm very confuse using that.

Comment: how you are building react modules. ?

Answer (score 0):

Current module is not possible. you have to use atleast [browserify](http://browserify.org) or [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). because these are in es6. as you can see import and export keyworkds will not work in browser. so you have to transpile or build them yourself. there is no need for node.js learning only you need to know how to use npm. just install node.js and npm comes by default with it. if you are using windows then it would be very easy. 
for using with browserify you can use

```
npm install -g browserify
```

next build the react-emoji and use it as script.

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks in advance. but I still not yet success build that. I'll try again.